# How to use Asp.Net LocalHost in Emulator Android BlueStack

Tags: asp.net, web-services, android-studio

I want to use `ASP.NET IISExpress` in `Emulator Android BlueStack`

`IISExpress ASP.NET`:

[image: IIS Express]

Emulator Android BlueStack:

[image: Android bluestack]

Answer (score 0):

replace http://localhost with http://10.0.2.2 it should working